# How to Create (and remove) AzFunctions at runtime

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-functions-runtime

I’m planning to build a mediator service to dynamically bind to various azure service bus subscriptions. This is to facilitate the http callback  pattern using Azure service bus to manage the clients offset and AzFunc for circuit breaker scenarios.

**What I need to do is :**  I need to create (and remove) function/bindings at runtime. Could someone shed some light on best practice?

I understand that Logic Apps might be better suited but we’re developing in an enterprise environment and have limited components available e.g. AzFunctions and AzService Bus

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this requirement by modify the function.json(modify the binding in function.json), please refer to the rest api below to edit your function.json.

1. Use Kudu API to change function.json https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API

PUT https://{functionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/{pathToFunction.json}, Headers: If-Match: "*", Body: new function.json content.

2. Then send request to apply changes.

POST https://{functionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/synctriggers